# Typescript compiler cannot find locally installed npm module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am building a typescript module that I am going to share between a node server and an angular2 app, but require doesn't seem to be able to find it after it is installed. Here is my shared module

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyCommonLibrary",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.9"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions":{
        "target":"es5",
        "module":"commonjs",
        "declaration":true,
        "sourceMap":true,
        "sourceRoot":"src",
        "outDir":"bin"
    },
    "exclude":[
        "node_modules",
        "bin",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

src/index.ts

```
export class TestClass {
    name:string;
    constructor(name:string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to compile properly, my bin/index.js looks good.
I run

> "npm install ../MyCommonLibrary --save"

from the server project and the module installs correctly. But then I get an error when I try to compile,

> cannot find module 'MyCommonLibrary'

Even though the MyCommonLibrary exists in the node_modules directory and seems to have all the proper information

server.ts

```
import express = require('express');
import myCommonLibrary = require('MyCommonLibrary');
var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Hello World');
})

var server = app.listen(3000,function(){
    var host:string = server.address().address;
    var port:number = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Any insight would be appreciated

**EDIT:** After doing a lot of digging I wound up finding a solution! From [this example](https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module) I found that adding

> "typings":"bin/index",

To my package.json fixes the issue, even though the Atom Typescript plugin still complains, tsc compiles just fine.

Comment: Can you check by setting the `moduleResolution` property to `node` in your `tsconfig.json` (compilerOptions) ?

Comment: Setting the moduleResolution to node fixes the issue I was having with the Atom typescript plugin, but does not fix the compile issue oddly enough. Adding the typings options to package.json fixed the compile issue.

Comment: Has been answered in [this other S/O question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript)