# How to consume npm modules from typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I'm giving a shot at typescript. It works fine at the hello world stage. I'm now trying to use a npm module :

`index.ts` =

```
import _ = require('lodash')

console.log(_.toUpper('Hello, world !'))
```

This doesn't work :

- `tsc index.ts` -> `Cannot find module 'lodash'. (2307)`
- `node-ts index.js` -> `Cannot find module 'lodash'. (2307)`

Looking at typescript documentation and in google didn't help. Other S/O questions are either unanswered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105803/typescript-compiler-cannot-find-locally-installed-npm-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309361/using-npm-modules-in-typescript)) or unrelated.

Elements :

- typescript 1.8 latest
- Yes, lodash is installed `npm i --save lodash` and exists in my filesystem (checked)
- I also did `typings i --save lodash`
- variants `import * as _ from 'lodash'` or `const _ = require('lodash')` don't work either
- I tried tweaking tsconfig.json options as suggested in other answers  `"moduleResolution": "node"` and `"module": "commonjs"` as suggested in some answers, still doesn't work

How do we consume a npm package in typescript ??

Comment: Did you add reference to lodash.d.ts in your index.ts? It should look similar to this: 
`///<reference path="../typings/lodash/lodash.d.ts"/>`

Comment: @Granga It works. Can you add this as an answer ?

Comment: Glad it works. Blackus has already added the answer and it specifies what I suggested even better. One note though: **When input files are specified on the command line(which is your case), tsconfig.json files are ignored.** ([source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html))

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*[2018/12] New, up-to-date, answer to this question I asked in 2016, which stills shows a lot of activity despite having outdated answers.*

Long story short, TypeScript requires **type informations** about your package's code (a.k.a. "[type declaration files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)" a.k.a. "typings") and rightfully tells you that you would otherwise be losing the whole point of TypeScript. There are several solutions to provide them or opt out of them, listed here in order of best practice:

---

**Solution 0**: the module already provides the typings. If its package.json contains a line like this:

```json
"typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
```

it is already TypeScript-enabled. It's most likely not the case if you are reading this page, so let's continue...

---

**Solution 1**: use community-contributed typings from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). For a module "foo", try this:

```bash
npm add -D @types/foo
```

if it works, jackpot! You now have the typings and can use your module. If npm complains that it can't find the module @types/foo, let's continue...

---

**Solution 2**: provide custom typings about this module. (with an option to do zero effort)

1. Create a folder named "typings-custom" at the root of your project
2. Reference the content of this folder in your tsconfig.json:

```json
"include": [
    "./typings-custom/**/*.ts"
]
```

3. Create a file with this exact name: foo.d.ts [foo = the name of the module] with the content:

```bash
declare module 'foo'
```

Your TypeScript code should now compile, albeit with NO type information (TypeScript consider the foo module of type "any").

You can also attempt to write the type information yourself, looking at the [official doc](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) and/or at examples from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). If you do, think of contributing your typings either directly into the module (solution 0, if the module author accepts) or into DefinitelyTyped (solution 1)

Comment: @Offirmo, We can also declare multiple custom typings in a single file as well!
So, No need for multiple files (Maybe?).

Comment: Step 2. `Reference the content of this folder in your tsconfig.json:` gives the following error: 
`Unknown compiler option 'include'.`

Comment: @Sumit it's not a compiler option, it should be a sibling of `compilerOptions`

Comment: When I add the include line, TS no longer recognizes React itself. `This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.` except I have ` "esModuleInterop": true` in my TSConfig

Comment: I think Solution 3 should be from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396763/2290413

Answer (score 68):

*[EDIT] Thanks a lot for this answer! However, as of 2018, it is outdated. Readers, have a look at the other answers.*

There are several ways to import modules from npm. But if you don't get typings, `tsc` will always complain that it can't find the module you are requiring (even if transpiled js *is actually* working).

- If you do have typings and do not use a `tsconfig.json`, use `reference` to import the typings:

  ```
  /// <reference path="path/to/typings/typings.d.ts" />

  import * as _ from 'lodash`;

  console.log(_.toUpper('Hello, world !'))
  ```
- If you are using a `tsconfig.json` file, be sure to have your typings file included (or not excluded, your choice), and make the `import` like on the previous example.

In the case when there is no available typings. You have two choices: write your own on a `.d.ts` file, or ignore type checking for the library.

To completely ignore the type checking (this is no the recommended way), import the library on a variable of type `any`.

```
 const _: any = require('lodash');

 console.log(_.toUpper('Hello, world !'))
```

`tsc` will complain that `require` doesn't exist. Provide `node` typings, or `declare` it to discard the error.

Comment: Complete answer with 3 solutions. +1

Comment: Addition: it even works with [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) as long as the typings index is referenced in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Im confused by what you mean to "declare it to discard the error." Do I need to make this change in the module I am trying to import?

Comment: This answer is severely outdated. See my new answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/53786892/587407

Answer (score 30):

**You're probably missing the [Declaration Files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).**

See [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) for more info.

---

Try this:

```
npm install --save lodash
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Now you can import.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

---

If the module you're importing has *multiple exports*, you can do this:

```
import { Express, Router } from 'express';
```

---

If the module you're importing *"has no default export"* you need to do this:

```
import * as http from 'http';
```

Comment: Why do we have to use `* as _` and not just `_ from 'lodash'` as in ES6 code?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Good point. Using `import _ from 'lodash';` is better in this case. I've updated my answer to show different ways to import and why you would use them.

Comment: The `* as _ ` is needed if the module has no default export. The tsc compiler will warn of this.

Comment: By 'no default export' does that mean no Typescript types defined (i.e. importing a plain JavaScript module)? I'm new to JS/Typescript....

Comment: @BigRich "No default export" means the module doesn't have an `export default <...>` statement. Take a look at the "Default exports" section of the [Typescript Modules Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me.

1. Create a folder named "typings".
2. In typings folder, create a file name *module-name.d.ts*. It contains:

   `declare module "module-name";`
3. In tsconfig.json, refer to the folder

   `"typeRoots": [
     "./typings",
     "../node_modules/@types"
   ]`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for contributing. This method is already included in my answer and should be used only as a last resort.

Comment: The step 3: `In tsconfig.json, refer to the folder`, gives the following error: `Unknown compiler option 'typesRoots'.`

Comment: @Sumit in my case, "typesRoots" is inside "compilerOptions"

Comment: It's typeRoots not typesRoots, and should be inside compilerOptions

Answer (score 3):

**I've been getting this error and none of the answers worked for me** but i figure out something when you want to work with node module in typescript install them as

```
$npm install @types/<module_name>
```

**for example**

```
npm install @types/cheerio
```

**instead of saying**

```
npm install cheerio
```