# Getting errors: How can I properly consume my transpiled and typed typescript npm module from typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I'm [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript) giving a shot at typescript. I've written a trivial "hello world" typescript module and [published it to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hello-world-emo). Really trivial, just does a default export:

```
export default function hello(target: string = 'World'): void
{
    console.log(`Hello, ${target} :-(`)
}
```

It is consumed perfectly well by node.js 0.10 -> 6.
The module also has a proper `"typings"` property in package.json, pointing to an existing `.d.ts` file generated by tsc [as explained in the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) :

```
export default function hello(target?: string): void;
```

However, I can't get it consumed by typescript code, neither in typescript 1.8 nor 2 :

```
import hello = require('hello-world-emo')

hello()
hello('Offirmo')
```

Transpiling with `tsc` or executing with `ts-node` both give the same error message:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
hello.ts (3,1): Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. (2349)
```

However, the generated .js works. It just seems a typing issue. Using other import formats like `import hello from 'hello-world-emo'` doesn't work either.

What is typescript complaining ? What did I miss ?

In case you want to inspect `tsconfig`, the module is [here](https://github.com/Offirmo/hello-world-npm) and I'm consuming it from [here](https://github.com/Offirmo/cross-js-env-tests/blob/master/typescript/v1/hello.ts)

Comment: Questions was also asked directly on Typescript GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not in typescript but rather in **ES6/CommonJS interop** : there is no perfect matching between ES6 and CommonJS exports, *especially for the ES6 "export default"*, cf. [this article](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/) and [this open issue on webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/706).

Here the module code is written in ES6 using ES6 modules. The build procedure is:

1. transpile typescript to ES6 with `tsc` (typescript compiler)
2. transpile the ES6 code and bundle it with `rollup`+babel for:

   - ES6@node4 / CommonJS (1st class citizen)
   - ES5@node0.10 / CommonJS (for still widely used legacy)
   - ES5 / umd (for browsers)

Node 4 (stable) being the 1st class citizen, the corresponding bundle (ES6@node4 / CommonJS) is exposed via the npm "main" entry. It has been converted to CommonJS as best as rollup could do, making it **consumable by node 4 but no longer by typescript**.

Another option would have been to transpile to ES5/CommonJs with `tsc`, **which adds special annotations for linking back CommonJS to ES6 modules**. But then it's 1) no longer bundled 2) more roughly transpiled (not using ES6 features included in node 4) and 3) more hardly consumable by node

**A compromise solution**: avoid the CommonJS / ES6 modules interop problem by **not using `export default`** but only named exports. This mitigation technique only downside is for node 4 :

- ES6: `import hello from '...'` becomes `import { hello } from '...'` **OK**
- node >=6: `const hello = require('...')` becomes `const { hello } = require('...')` **OK**
- node <=4: `var hello = require('...')` becomes `var hello = require('...').hello` **less elegant but acceptable**