# Guid class in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using Node as backend and I was looking for a class that could generate Guid for me. I came across https://www.npmjs.com/package/guid

I installed it as npm install guid.

However, I am not sure how to import it in my class before I can actually use it.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript/38225401#38225401) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guid like this:

```
npm install guid
```

Require it where u want to use

```
Guid = require('guid');
```

for creating a new Guid

```
guid = Guid.create(); //will give u guid object

guid.value; 
// will give u -> '7bf5b258-2f03-ad87-eca7-c868819d4c34'
```

you can check `guid` using equals method

```
guid.equals('7bf5b258-2f03-ad87-eca7-c868819d4c34') 
// -> true
```