# How do you validate Ip address in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ip-address

Given an IPv4 or IPv6 address determine if the address is a valid input. This has to be done using Typescript.

I wanted to use an NPM library [ip-address](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-address) as it seemed to meet all of my needs, but i couldnt get it to properly import and use it.

```js
import {ipv4, ipv6} from 'ip-address'

var address = new ipv4(value)
if(address.IsValid){
// do work
}
```

I expected this to work after importing the npm module, but i get "package not found".

Comment: Did you install the npm package?

Comment: it was installed. i posted the solution. I didnt add it to my @Types

Comment: +7.5Mo of NPM packages to validate IPv4 addresses? Mmh... Why not simply use `/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/.match(value)` (or other [more precises regexes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html))?

Comment: I required more than just validating the address using a regex. I needed to know if the address was also in a specific subnet.

Answer (score 1):

After [looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620201/6214681) I found that I was not importing my npm modules correctly.

Using VS19, Open Tools -> VS Command Prompt ->

```
npm install --save ip-address
npm install --save @types/ip-address
```

Then in the project file I imported the [ip-address](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip-address) following the guidelines.

```
import * as IpAddress from 'ip-address';
export var ipv4 = IpAddress.Address4;
export var ipv6 = IpAddress.Address6;
```

then you can just call the `var address = new ipv4(value)`

Answer (score 0):

As google ranks this on top for 'typescript type ip address' and the following info also answers the question perfectly (just with another package) I want to note that **the package [ipaddr.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipaddr.js) seems to be smaller and much more common**.

Stats according to [NPM Trends](https://npmtrends.com/ip-address-vs-ipaddr.js) as of Aug. 2023

| package | weekly downloads | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ipaddr.js | 35.252.234 | 3.6KB |
| ip-address | 465.104 | 12.5KB |

According to [this](https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js/issues/93) typescript definitions are included in ipaddr.js since v1.6.0 (2018)