# How to import npm packages from a typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this in my typescript project

```
import * as schedule from "node-schedule";
import * as ACTIONS from "../../../actions";
```

The bottom one resolves, but the top one does not. It is a node package I got from doing `npm install node-schedule`. I get

```
Cannot find module 'node-schedule' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

How can I import that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume npm modules from typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install its types package..

```
npm install --save @types/node-schedule
```