# Someone knows how can i declare types for instascan library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, instascan

I just need to implement **instascan** with typescript, but i cant find any information on internet about its types. I tried to declare and export "fake" modules, but i cant handle it works

/index.d.ts

```
declare module "Instascan" {
    export class Camera {
        //..
    }
}
```

/main.ts

```
import {Camera} from "Instascan";

// .. //
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume npm modules from typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224232/how-to-consume-npm-modules-from-typescript)

Comment: No, is more about to create just types for an already existent library

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53786892/8289918) on that question explains how to use your own typings.